# Como verificar que o executável foi alterado? C#

Tags: c#

Alguem poderia me ajudar, eu estou tentando verificar se o execultavel foi renomeado, tipo

Demo.exe (tem que ser assim sempre)

se alterar ele dar o erro
O Arquivo deve ter o nome 'Demo'.

e nao permitir abrir o arquivo se nao tiver o nome certo.

o problema que nao estou sabendo fazer a verificação...

em meu codigo soh conseguir verificar se ele esta na pasta, porem se ter um Demo e outro com qualquer nome ele abre...

segue o codigo.

```
private string ExecutablePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

if (File.Exists(ExecutablePath + @"\Demo.exe"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O Arquivo deve ter o nome \'Demo\'.", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
```

desde ja obrigado.

Comment: desse jeito o máximo que vai fazer é verificar se o arquivo existe na pasta, não dá pra ver ser foi alterado se não souber o nome.  O mais perto disso seria fazer um aplicativo que ficasse executando o tempo todo e monitorasse a pasta para ver quando acontece alguma alteração, mas se ele parar por algum motivo vai perder as alterações. Para isso tem a classe `FileSystemWatcher `

Comment: Não nao, eu queria soh permitir que o arquivo abra se tiver o nome Demo.exe, caso contrario de o erro. sempre que abrir verificar se ta certo o nome, se mudar ele nao executa.

Comment: Ah entendi, veja se isso resolve, ai posso postar uma resposta mais detalhada: `if (System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName == "Demo.exe")`

Comment: seria +/- isso msm, porem nao estou conseguindo colocar esse codigo no Demo.exe, se for em outro form da certo, mais nele proprio nao abre o arquivo, mais gera o erro caso mude o nome...

Comment: mas se funciona o `FrindlyName` já tem como comparar, agora se está dando erro é outro problema. Qual erro ocorre?

Comment: @RicardoPontual deu certo, era um erro meu kkk

Comment: ok, deixei como resposta abaixo. boa sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso pode usar [CurrentDomain.FrindlyName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.friendlyname?view=netframework-4.8)

```
if (!System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName == "Demo.exe")
{
   MessageBox.Show("O Arquivo deve ter o nome \'Demo\'.", "Error");
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: vlw msm era isso msm...

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo Pretti Fantin, a classe Process tem um método chamado GetCurrentProcess que retorna uma referência para o processo que está sendo executado no momento (sua aplicação). Com essa referência em mãos, basta consultar a propriedade ProcessName.

```
// Obtém o nome do processo atual (esta aplicação)

    Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
```

Sua rotina para verificação ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // Obtém o nome do processo atual (esta aplicação)
    string meuProcesso = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

    // Procura o processo atual na lista de processos que
    // estão a ser executados neste momento, no computador
    Process[] processos = Process.GetProcessesByName(meuProcesso);

    // Além desta instância, já existe mais alguma?
    if (processos != null && processos.Length > 1)
    {
        // Mostra uma mensagem, e termina esta instância...
        MessageBox.Show("Só pode haver um!!", "Highlander :)");
    }
    else
    {
        // Permite executar a aplicação
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

[Como saber o nome do Executavel em RunTime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/71ce5f79-4505-4590-8f82-90020b22d84d/como-saber-o-nome-do-executavel-em-runtime?forum=vscsharppt)

Comment: essa verificação eu ja uso, o problema eh verificar se o nome do .exe foi modificado, ele soh pode abrir o .exe se for Demo.exe se estiver Demo2.exe ele eh pra gerar um erro e fechar...